# Mapbox geocoding search result in infobox

Tags: jquery, mapbox, geocoding, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to create a map where every time a user searches using a geocoder, an info box appears on top of the map with the attributes of the tileset underneath the geocoding result (point). I am able to trigger a pop up to appear every time geocoder is used, and was able to successfully make infobox appear whenever I click anywhere on the map using "map.queryRenderedFeatures", but trying to combine the two has been unsuccessful. It seems somehow map.queryRenderedFeatures doesn't like to work with the coordinates from the geocoding (geometry.coordinates). Could anyone help me?

```
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'xxxxx';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'xxxxx',
    center: [-95.925, 29.575],
    zoom: 7
    });


  var businessgeocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    zoom: 15,
    placeholder: 'Business location',
     marker: {
     color: 'red'
     },
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl
    })


  map.addControl(businessgeocoder);


 map.on('load', function() {
      businessgeocoder.on('result', function(resultinfobox) {
          
          
          var point = map.project([resultinfobox.result.center[0], resultinfobox.result.center[1]]); 
                  console.log([resultinfobox.result.center[0], resultinfobox.result.center[1]])
                  console.log(point)
          var test = map.queryRenderedFeatures(point, {
              layers: ['tract-4332-1sbuyl','blockgroups-4332-9mehvk'] 
              });
              if (!test.length) {
                 return;
                 }
               var censustracts = test[0];
               var censusblockgroups = test[1];
              
              console.log(censusblockgroups.properties.LMIPerc)
      });
    });
    

  
  
  map.on('click', function(clickinfobox) {
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(clickinfobox.point, {
                 layers: ['tract-4332-1sbuyl','blockgroups-4332-9mehvk'] 
                 });

  if (!features.length) {
    return;
  }

  var censustract = features[0];
  var censusblockgroup = features[1];
  var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: [0, -15] })
    .setLngLat(clickinfobox.lngLat)
    .setHTML('<h4>' + censustract.properties.CountyName + '</h4><h4>' + censustract.properties.NAMELSAD + '</h4><h4>' + censusblockgroup.properties.NAMELSAD + '</h4>' +
             '<table><tr><th></th><th>CT</th><th>BG</th></tr><tr><td>Poverty Rate</td><td>' 
             + censustract.properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td><td>' 
             + censusblockgroup.properties.PovRate + "%" + '</td></tr><tr><td>LMI</td><td>' 
             + censustract.properties.LMIPerc + "%" + '</td><td>' + censusblockgroup.properties.LMIPerc + "%" + '</td></tr></table>'
            )
    .addTo(map);
  });  
    

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fallen into this trap so many times.

`map.queryRenderedFeatures()` takes *screen* coordinates, in *pixels*. Not *geographic* coordinates in *degrees*.

You can use `map.project(result.geometry.coordinates)` to get the screen coordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is very helpful to know. However... I used it but it still doesn't work... Please see my edits above...

Comment: You need to ask specific questions, and demonstrate what you have tried, and what failed exactly. Not "it still doesn't work".

Comment: That's why I was referring you to the code, as it demonstrates what I have tried more accurately. After reading your comment, I created a variable >>> point = map.project([resultinfobox.result.center[0], resultinfobox.result.center[1]]); <<< and fed that in to the queryRenderedFeatures() but it is still not being registered. I am using console logs to find what is actually being fed but still cannot seem to find the format the queryRenderedFeatures() wants as an input.